# perl: print text with rounded equation result in a single line

Tags: perl

When I try to print this line in perl, it gives me the following output,

> print "False Positive = ",($G_FP_1+$G_FP_2)*$percent,"\n";

Result

> False Positive = 39.8980169971671

However I would like the results to be rounded to 2 decimals, like 39.89, how can I force perl to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your number rounded to 2 decimals is `39.90`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
printf "False Positive = %0.2f\n", ($G_FP_1+$G_FP_2) * $percent;
```